# php src value change in a hidden div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to get the file name of pdf/image to display it in a table locally. When I get the name of the file, I want it to be in a `<a>` tag which then href to the hidden pop out div inside it is `<embed>`. The problem is that the value of the src does not change and all the file names are the same (it takes the first name for all)

Here is my code:

```html
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search)){
    ?>
<div aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="login-forms" class="modal leread-modal fade in">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" name="place">
      <embed src="stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" id="up" type="application/pdf" width="600px" height="500px" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer footer-box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I used jQuery to change the value of the src attribute in the `<embed>` tag, but the result is the last name of the file (last row in the database)

Here is the code

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){                                                
      $('#up').attr('src',"stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>");
    });
 </script>
```

Here is the whole loop

```
if(mysql_num_rows($search)>0){ ?>

<div class="container-table10">
    <div class="wrap-table100">
        <div class="table100">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table100-head">
                        <th class="column1">appeal date</th>
                        <th class="column2">course code</th>
                        <th class="column3">date of exam </th>
                        <th class="column4">reason</th>
                        <th class="column5">course title</th>
                        <th class="column6">AY</th>
                        <th class="column7">semester</th>
                        <th class="column8">student id</th>
                        <th class="column8">Lecturer
                            <br>Name</th>
                        <th class="column9">upload</th>
                        <th class="column9">Eligibility</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <?php
                                        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search)){

                                                ?>
                        <div aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="login-forms" class="modal leread-modal fade in">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body" name="place">

                                    <embed src="stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" class="up" type="application/pdf" width="600px" height="500px" />
                                    <script>
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            $('.up').attr('src', "stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>");
                                        });
                                    </script>

                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer footer-box">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="column1">
                                <?php echo $row['appealm_date'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column2">
                                <?php echo $row['course_code'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column3">
                                <?php echo $row['date_of_exam'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column4"><a class="login modal-form" data-target="#login-form" data-toggle="modal" href="#">show</a></td>
                            <td class="column5">
                                <?php echo $row['course_title'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column6">
                                <?php echo $row['appealm_ay'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column7">
                                <?php echo $row['appealm_sem'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column8">
                                <?php echo $row['student_id'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column8">
                                <?php echo $row['lecturer_name'];?>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column9">
                                <a class="login modal-form" id="aaa" data-toggle="modal" href="#login-forms">
                                    <?php echo $row['upload'];?>
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="column8">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="eli" id="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="login-form" class="modal leread-modal fade in">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">

                                <div id="login-content" class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button aria-label="Close" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Reason</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                        <p class="p">
                                            <?php echo $row['appealm_reason'];?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer footer-box">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php   
                                        }
                                            ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php   
   }}
 }}
?>
```

If there is another way to have the file pop out in the same page, please suggest it.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

use `class` instead of `id` .Id is unique

```
<embed src="stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" class="up" type="application/pdf" width="600px" height="500px" />
```

And change the respective  js element `id` to `class`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.up').attr('src',"stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>");
 });
```

Comment: are you change the src  as individual with respected php `$row` or same value for all embed src ?

Comment: $row holds more than one value, i tired to change the src value for each row with the appropriate $row['upload'].

Answer (score 0):

Use the class attribute instead of id. An ID is supposed to be unique (this means only used once).

You can only access `$row[]` inside your while loop, since you're looping through `$search` which is a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Is it possible to see the whole while loop? @MaxedTyaertyaery

Comment: <embed src="stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" class="up" id="up" type="application/pdf" width="600px" height="500px" /> @MaxedTyaertyaery

Comment: Added class="up" and tried before id="up" but still no luck

Comment: Ah ic, you're basically saying: change the src of of the element who has the class "up" to: $row['upload'].

Comment: Above the while(), you could make a new variable, let's call it $x.
Give it a value of 1.
$x = 1;
<embed src="stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" id="up-<?= $x; ?>" type="application/pdf" width="600px" height="500px" />

jQuery:
<script>
                                             $(document).ready(function(){
                                                 $('#up-<?= $x; ?>').attr('src',"stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>");
                                             });</script>

Comment: Yes but it keeps repeating the same value for all.

Comment: Oh i forgot, you have to increment $x at the of the loop. ($x++)

Comment: $x = 1;
while(row=mysql_fetch_assoc($search)) {
    // Code....
    $x++;
}

Answer (score 0):

1. in your loop use `<a href="#login-forms" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-forms" data-url="stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>">XXX</a>`
2. If you are using bootstrap, add

`$('#login-forms').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $("#up").attr("src", $invoker.data("url"));
});`

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `$row['upload']` is only one value, that changes each time through the `while` loop.  When you changed `up` to a class from an id, you made your script essentially redefine the `src` for every `up` already on the page each time it runs.  A better solution would be to define a better `id`, since you're only intending to change a single `embed`.  Would it be possible to use `$row['upload']` as your id?

```
 <embed src="stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" id="<?php echo $row['upload'];?>" type="application/pdf" width="600px" height="500px" />
```

Then you could change your script to:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#'+<?php echo $row['upload'];?>).attr('src',"stuUploads/<?php echo $row['upload'];?>");
      });
</script>
```

Comment: For reference, it's not super clear that this would have any effect whatsoever on the page, since the php prints `$row['upload']`in the `src` just prior to the script doing the same thing.

Comment: I tried it, still didn't work, thank you for your help.